# Datatables large data json with "smart searching", or server side with regex, or better approach?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, datatables, large-data

I'm building this Bible app with Datatables.

My problem is, the data is big. Total is approximately 500 MB.
It's only about 32,000 lines, but they are paragraphs of text with heavy html/css markup.

Searching needs to be "smart searching" (partial word match).

It looks like there are 2 possible options to store the data:

1. I can have the data live in a mysql table. I know how to implement server side processing, but I don't know how to implement regex searching. It's been done successfully in a couple of ways here: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/3343/server-side-processing-and-regex-search-filter/p1 (I don't know enough php to understand how to).
2. I can have the data live in one or perhaps even multiple json files. Then have the user download all once into local storage. Then perform Datatables smart searching normally. I'm not sure the searching will be good though. I tried this offline, loading only 50 MB and the searching is already quite slow. (Again, my programming knowledge is very limited).

Please have a look and feel free to guide me in the right direction :)

http://torah.byethost14.com/AdminLTE-master/pages/tables/_talmidimEdition.html

Comment: You dont/shouldnt need regex searching. Use full text searching, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html.

Answer (score 0):

"Heavy html/css markup"?  Will you be searching for html tags?  Probably not.  So...

Have another column that is the pure text -- no markup, no html, no css, not even verse numbers.  (Book an verse number should probably be in separate columns.)

Then add a `FULLTEXT` index to that pure text column.  Be aware of the limitations of fulltext.

`REGEXP` is slow, and will always scan all rows in the table.

There are also a few fulltext search engines that can be added onto MySQL.  (I do not have advice on whether they are applicable for your app.)

Comment: The "Heavy html/css markup" is obviously because of the "red letter" feature as well as other text which will be bold, italic, etc, etc. But you are correct, I will not be searching for html tags.

An additional (hidden) column with the pure text, for the purpose of searching, means an additional 32000 Bible verses, in addition to the 96000 already there because 3 Bibles are displayed in the 3 columns.

In either case, does FULLTEXT allow for multiple words and partial word matching?

Comment: `FULLTEXT` can search for multiple words, either 'requiring' all words, or ordering by some builtin metric.  There is automatic 'stemming' (aimed at English) and 'prefix' searching.

Comment: The entire Bible is only 4M characters of raw text; this is a trivial amount to add as an extra column.  How did you get to 500MB?  You might need a flag on the row for 'quote of Jesus'?